# Connection failure over VPN hosted SQL server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, vpn

I'm trying to connect to a remote SQL Server database through a VPN client. I'm using the connection settings to test the connection in Visual Studio 2013 for Web. I've tried the same procedure over a computer on the same network at the place where I work and it connects successfully.

I can connect through the VPN to the server. I get back a successful ping to the server listening on port 4500.  I've tried the server name and the IP address with the port number. I've tried leaving it default and with the SQL Server port default. I use SQL Server authentication with the correct username and password, and the db name is also correct. All this done while connected to the VPN.

I've tried the settings for both OLE DB and SQL Server.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default SQL Server port is 1433 (although, as you mention, you've successfully connected while on the same network. I’ll assume you’re setup on 4500). I'd recommend checking firewall rule/port settings on the client machine you’re trying to connect from (as a quick test, you could temporarily switch your firewall off before fiddling with firewall rules). Also, if possible, check that the VPN allows connections over the port; it’s less likely than firewall, depends on what and how the VPN’s setup.

Comment: Turns out Visual Studio needed SQL Management Studio installed to get this to run properly.  Thanks for the help.